# Google Api Error: permissionDeclarationRequiresUpdate

Tags: android, android-manifest

My app was taken down from ply store because I was using SMS. I have addressed this issue with SmsRetriever and removed all the SMS permissions I was requesting.

Now when I try and upload to the play store I get the error `Google Api Error: permissionDeclarationRequiresUpdate: Permissions declaration for the app requires an update`

If I goto play store I am seeing the following

`You can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions`

New permissions added
Warning:

Users that have the APK with version code 129 may need to accept the android.permission.CAMERA permission, which may result in them not upgrading to this version of the app.

Tip:

Ensure that the new permissions are necessary, and consider mentioning these permissions in the What's new in this release text.

Any thought or suggestion on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Am assuming you are using some sort of a CI.

You need to upload a new build manually with a different version code for other subsequent CI builds to work.

When you create the new release you will get a Permission declaration form. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?p=perm_form&visit_id=636857339052822848-3118898021&rd=1

In that declaration form you will have the option

> Declare your app's compliance with the Permissions policy.

Select No and check the other options at the bottom.

Submit and wait for their review.